# How to display picked image in a uiimageview taken from the photo library to another uiimageview in a different view controller?

Tags: iphone, ios

So far this is my code, It allows me to pick a photo from the photo gallery and display it in an image view in one controller, the view controller has a button which has a segue that sends it to the next view controller in this view controller is another image view.

I want the image view in the first controller to be displayed in the second imageview in the second view controller this is my code so far.

I am not sure what steps to take to implement this so any help in steps to take would be appreciated, I tried various things but I think I'm not doing it so right, so i decided to give it a clean slate and get some advice

Viewcontroller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,  UINavigationControllerDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *chosenImage;

@property(strong, nonatomic) UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;


@end
```

Viewcontroller.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()

@end


@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *myGrabbedImage = @"myGrabbedImage.png";
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,          NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:myGrabbedImage];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
    [[self imageView]setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
}
- (IBAction)chooseImage:(id)sender
{
    self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
    [self.imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    [self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    self.chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.chosenImage);
    NSString *myGrabbedImage = @"myGrabbedImage.png";
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];

    [self.imageView setImage:self.chosenImage];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    NSString *fullPathToFile = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:myGrabbedImage];
    [data writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:YES];


}


- (void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}




@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `UIImage` property on your second ViewController and pass the image via `prepareForSegue`

(Don't forget to import your second ViewController so `ViewController` knows about it)

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"yourSegueIdentifier"]) {
        yourSecondViewController *secondVC = [segue destinationViewController];
        secondVC.nextImage = self.chosenImage;
    }

}
```

then in your second ViewController you can set the imageView

```
yourSecondImageView.image = nextImage;
```